Homeless encampment (leased or owned), do we have to follow an eviction process?
If we know of an encampment on our property (leased or owned) and we don’t do anything, do we then become the landlord and have to follow an eviction process? Because we didn't do anything, are we liable for injury (trip and fall etc)

If this is actually happening, you need to talk to a lawyer. If it's hypothetical, you at least need to specify the jurisdiction (country, state, city, etc) in which it is hypothetically happening.

This question is similar to: What is the landowner liability for homeless encampments on property?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Where? This varies greatly from place to place.
